# Passing byte array from C to Lua

Tags: arrays, lua

I'm trying to pass a byte array from C to lua. 
If I pass it as a string I cannot pass arrays that contain "0x00" (because it is interpreted as the end of the string). That's what I wrote so far:

C:

```
uchar hash[32];
memset(hash, 0, 32);

sha256_final(ctx, hash);
lua_pushstring(L, (const char*)hash);
return 1;
```

Lua:

```
local hash_str = shaFunctions.final(ctx)
local hash = {}
hash_str:gsub(".",function(c) table.insert(hash,string.byte(c)) end)
```

Is there a better way for passing a byte array from C to Lua?
Thanks

Comment: Use `lua_pushlstring`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lua_pushlstring()` function.

This is the prototype:

```
void lua_pushlstring (lua_State *L, const char *s, size_t len);
```

and your code will look like this:

```
uchar hash[32];
memset(hash, 0, 32);

sha256_final(ctx, hash);
lua_pushlstring(L, (const char*)hash, 32);
return 1;
```